# How do I specify the highest version of window installer in WiX?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I use WiX 3.6 to build a msi package for an application. Can I somehow specify to use features available for Windows Installer 3.1 and issue errors if the features from higher versions used?

Comment: As far as I know, it is only possible to specify the minimum version of the Windows Installer (in the `Package` element).

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Should an error be issued if I specify InstallerVersion="301" inside Package element and use a functionality available only in MSI 5.0?

Comment: If you utilize a feature of MSI 5.0, and MSI 5.0 is not installed on a target machine, then it will issue an error (I hope that's the case). Instead you should put an appropriate condition to the MSI 5.0-specific areas, and author the alternative to be run in case MSI version is lower.

Comment: Basically, you have two reliable options: 1) find out your OS prerequisites, and stick with the lowest version of MSI embedded, or 2) author a bundle and install the required version of the Windows Installer before proceeding with the main installation. In the second case you always bring the right version of MSI with you. But the downside is the size of the installation and some extra complexity related to author and maintain a bundle instead of a pure MSI package

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `Package/@InstallerVersion="301"` and run validation, you'll get build-time errors if you use features that aren't available in that version of MSI.

Comment: How do I run the validation?

Comment: It runs by default in WiX v3.x and you can do so manually using smoke.exe.